# How to correct misspelled product names?

Tags: python, openai-whisper

Moisturizer **Finty** Skin Hydrovisor
**Joa** Beauty Dark Circle Concealer
Sephora brow pencil

I have extracted these product names using audio transcription, but some products such as 'Fenty' and 'Joah' are misspelled.

An English text normalizer doesn't work on this and GPT-3 also doesn't seem to do a good job.

Is there a better approach to normalize the names to the actual product names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to normalize product names is to use a [spell checker](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/) or spell correction algorithm that can handle out-of-vocabulary words. This can help correct the misspelled product names such as 'Fenty' and 'Joah' to their correct spellings 'Fenty' and 'Joa'.

Another approach is to use named [entity recognition (NER)](https://medium.com/mysuperai/what-is-named-entity-recognition-ner-and-how-can-i-use-it-2b68cf6f545d) algorithms to identify the product names in the text and then map them to a known list of product names. NER algorithms can help identify the product names even if they are misspelled or written in different formats.